# Did a producer or creator of Star Wars Rebels state it would have only 5 seasons?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

Star Wars Rebels is set five years prior to 'A New Hope'. I seem to recall some comment when the series first started that the intended arc was for 5 seasons (those 5 years as it were) and not any more than that.

Is there an official source or word of God (even if plans have changed) to that effect? I just can't recall if that was something Filoni said in an interview or if it was interwebs speculation.

Comment: I'm more curious as to what Arrow will do after season five.

Comment: Who says a season must occur during a whole year? The seasons of 24 where only a day.

Comment: @RogueJedi - understand the future works thing. The question was intended to be more focused on whether or not an official rep of the show had stated something in the past (regardless of what will actually happen). I've updated the title to reflect to better reflect that

Comment: doesn't seem like a future works question to me, it seems to be specifically asking if anyone has stated if this show would only get 5 seasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update #2:

It has been confirmed that the upcoming fourth season of *Rebels* will also be its last.

[image]

### Old Answer:

I can find no statement that *Star Wars: Rebels* will only last five seasons. There's a [rumor](http://makingstarwars.net/2014/11/rumor-star-wars-rebels-last-3-4-seasons-sequel-trilogy-animated-series-follow/) that it will last three to four seasons, but I see no particular reason to believe it.

Time-wise, there's no real reason to limit the show to five seasons. *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* had six seasons and a movie, and it took place over less than three years. They could easily fit more than five seasons into five years if they wanted to. There's also no evidence that the series will stop once it reaches *A New Hope*.

**Update #1:** [Filoni has confirmed that the show could potentially continue past *A New Hope*](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-rebels-timeline-a-new-hope/).

> Well it’s a choice, right? It absolutely could. There would be nothing wrong with that if we chose that that was important for us to tell the story. We have surmised, over the years, that the Rebellion isn’t technically over until Return of the Jedi and even then there was some additional fighting that lead up to Jakku. So when is the ultimate victory that would mean Hera and company are free of the fight? Well, it doesn’t seem to be for a long time. So it’s not impossible and there are probably a lot of stories, I’m just gonna try and tell the most important ones for them, what their saga is, and probably not every saga ends on the same day.

Comment: I think the rumor you posted is what I was remembering - thanks!